# Travis isn't running post deploy commands on Heroku

Tags: heroku, travis-ci

I'm trying to move the post deploy commands from out of my `package.json`'s `postinstall` line, and instead to utilise the `run` object in my `.travis.yml` but it doesn't seem to invoke the commands.

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  run:
    - "npm install"
    - "node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
    - "node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt build:production"
  api_key:
    secure: ...
  app: node-snapshot
  on:
    repo: Wildhoney/Snapshot.js
```

Even when I remove the directory, and just invoke `bower install` it still does nothing. I've also done a `heroku run bash -a node-snapshot` and the `ls` for that shows a strange `vendor` directory in the root with `node` inside of it, but the Bower dependencies and the result of `grunt build:production` are nowhere to be found.

Ideas?

Comment: Just a note, `npm install` should be extraneous, as the buildpack should run that

Comment: Yep, understood. It was a feeble attempt to get things working.